# Cloudflare 522, 525 connection timed out

Tags: cloudflare

My website keeps giving 522 connection timeout error. we contacted the cloudflare support team and found that there are some packet loss. because of which we are getting this error.

Can you please help me how can we resolve the packet loss issue and fix  this problem asap.

below is the response received from the cloudflare support team

I have checked the network path from an example location where we saw the errors and I can see that there is some packet loss outside of our network reaching your origin server:

```
      HOST: ***                                 Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
  1.|-- 108.162.228.1                            0.0%    30   31.3   5.7   0.8  31.3   8.1
  2.|-- 141.101.67.64                            0.0%    30    1.3  13.2   0.4 179.9  35.5
  3.|-- 108.170.245.6                            0.0%    30    0.9   4.7   0.5  63.7  11.9
  4.|-- 209.85.248.117                           0.0%    30    1.1  44.3   1.1 1047. 190.4
  5.|-- 142.250.229.254                         20.0%    30  153.1 514.9 152.5 3253. 725.9
  6.|-- 216.239.57.136                          26.7%    30  152.9 348.4 152.2 1219. 407.3
  7.|-- 142.250.231.184                          0.0%    30  1216. 779.1 152.1 3286. 1171.2
  8.|-- 142.250.235.39                           3.3%    30  153.5 456.1 152.9 3266. 821.6
  9.|-- 209.85.247.43                            6.7%    30  158.4 431.8 158.4 3269. 667.3
 10.|-- 108.170.235.197                         26.7%    30  159.2 466.9 158.2 3211. 710.2
 11.|-- 172.253.72.135                          13.3%    30  1288. 636.1 159.2 3326. 880.8
 12.|-- 209.85.255.130                           3.3%    30  303.6 621.1 233.1 3371. 685.0
 13.|-- 209.85.245.232                          10.0%    30  300.5 315.0 290.7 387.7  22.3
 14.|-- 216.239.35.167                          10.0%    30  330.1 467.9 286.2 3409. 617.8
 15.|-- 66.249.95.23                            76.7%    30  302.5 312.4 299.5 364.3  23.0
 16.|-- ???                                     100.0    30    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 17.|-- ???                                     100.0    30    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 18.|-- ???                                     100.0    30    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 19.|-- ???                                     100.0    30    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 20.|-- ???                                     100.0    30    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
 21.|-- 205.177.185.35.bc.googleusercontent.com 96.7%    30  242.1 242.1 242.1 242.1   0.0
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling Cloudflare's proxy feature for the DNS record and checked if the problem goes away or stays the same? By the looks of the trace your server is behind some rather horrible links, so I'd recommend changing hosting providers or complaining to your current one.

Comment: yes i checked by disabling the cloudflare proxy feature for the dns record but still the problem is not getting resolved. we are hosted on google cloud.